# Line Debugging in ColdFusion 11 with CFEclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, coldfusion, coldfusion-11, cfeclipse

Has anyone had any luck in setting **line debugging** in Eclipse with the CFEclipse plugin?  The [instructions](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/developing-cfml-applications/using-the-coldfusion-debugger/set-up-coldfusion-to-use-the-debugger.html) seem to be for the actual ColdFusion IDE.  We are running ColdFusion 11.  I've been playing around with the line debugger in FusionDebug, but I would like to give the native debugger a try as well.  Does it require the ColdFusion IDE, or can it work within Eclipse with the CFEclipse plug-in?

Comment: There is no line debugger in CFEclipse. It's in CFBuilder, the Adobe developed, Eclipse based IDE for ColdFusion. CFEclipse is just a code editor.

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno - FWIW, there *used to be* an extension that allowed line debugging with CFEclipse, maybe back around CF8 or CF9 (?). Probably a precursor to what is in CFBuilder, I am guessing.

Comment: That seems to be consistent with what I've found as well.  There had been a line debugger tool for CFEclipse, but it no longer is supported.

Comment: Yes, even if you could find a copy (good luck), no guarantees it would even work anymore. Better to try the newer version in CFBuilder.

Comment: @Leigh Moved to an answer w/ more info.

Answer (score 4):

CFEclipse is just a code editor. Looking at the [feature list](http://cfeclipse.org/index.cfm/features/), it lists debugging, but only for CF 8:

> Adobe released the ColdFusion 8 Extensions for Eclipse which included a step debugger and RDS tools. This is no longer supported by Adobe but still works in the latest CFEclipse versions.

Once Adobe released [CFBuilder](http://www.adobe.com/products/coldfusion-builder.html), thier complete Eclipse-based IDE for ColdFusion (which includes a step-debugger), I'm sure they stopped releasing those Eclipse extensions for newer versions of ColdFusion. This would stop CFEclipse and other free Eclipse based editors from providing step-debugging for CF 9 or later.

An alternate step-debugger would be [FusionDebug](http://www.fusion-debug.com/), which I have used in the past to solve some serious problems in legacy code bases.