# How to add CFML project URL in CFEclipse

Tags: eclipse, coldfusion, cfml, cfeclipse

I checked with Google and seems like I am the only one having this problem. There are tutorials for a previous version of Eclipse there is nothing for the later versions.

I was able to set up my Eclipse installation to handle CFML projects with the help of CFEclipse plugin but I cannot find a way to give the project URL so that I can **start running and debugging** the CFML project.

I have tried checking all the project properties section and also the "Run configurations" sections. I think I am missing something. Does anybody know how project URL can be added?

I am using Eclipse Version: Neon.2 (4.6.2)

Comment: If you want line debugging, you need to use CFBuilder. CFEclipse does not do debugging. There [used to be an Adobe extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43052498/line-debugging-in-coldfusion-11-with-cfeclipse) which allowed debugging in conjunction with CFEclipse, but that was way back in CF8 and is no longer available AFAIK.